# How to quantify the amount of paracetamol present

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions

What is the most accurate way of determining the number of moles of paracetamol from a solution, mixed with acid or base?
I do not have access to more advanced laboratory methods like liquid chromatography, but can use methods such as titration and spectrophotometry.

Comment: http://www.rsc.org/learn-chemistry/resource/download/res00000925/cmp00001273/pdf

Comment: @orthocresol - to combat potential link rot, how about you summarize that link as an answer?

Comment: Alright - here we go. Paracetamol reacts with $\ce{Fe^3+}$ in a 1:1 ratio to give $\ce{Fe^2+}$ - exactly how I am not sure. You can then use a spectrophotometric method (e.g. reaction with $\ce{K3[Fe(CN)]6}$ to form Prussian blue) to quantify the amount of $\ce{Fe^2+}$ present.

Comment: will the above method still work if there solution already consists of other compounds such as 4-aminophenol and ethanoic acid?
what my experiment is trying to find out is whether pH affects the rate of hydrolysis of paracetamol.
so i will be using different acidic and basic solutions to hydrolyse as much paracetamol as possible in a fixed amount of time. After that, can i still apply the method you guys have mentioned?